# Can you see jungle timers when Spectating a game?

Tags: league-of-legends

When spectating a LoL game, can you see the jungle respawn timers? You can't tab to see the scores like when you are playing in the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from looking through all the controls in spectator mode, you cannot see regular jungle timers such as buffs or raptors etc, but it will show the timers for drakes, baron, elder dragon, and rift herald in the upper left corner of the screen. However, the time till they spawn won't be displayed until shortly before they are going to spawn (a few minutes I believe).